# Python code invokes different interpreter from shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

During zerphyr rtos installation process i ran into this error https://pastebin.com/8F5A8S8m, which i safely brute-forced by the link given in the next sentence, but now same error but different file. And here is the code from that file https://pastebin.com/EawPKXRG. So, in short, by googling i couldn't find a way to change interpreter that python uses in this particular files.
FYI

```
which python
```

gives python 3.11 one

```
sudo su
nano etc/path
```

gives also right directory for python 3.11, but somehow these files use python 3.9 which is installed on this mac by default.'

p.s sorry for the grammar and structure, I'm so mentally drained now to write it properly.

Didn't find anything on google

Answer (score 0):

So you need to run those python files in this format

```
python3.11 your_desired_file_name
```

Comment: I execute all this by typing "west build -p auto -b nucleo_l552ze_q samples/basic/blinky". How should I proceed now?